# multiple database swiching real time

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

please an example for use multiple data bases for my app in rails, i need create and save only one table internal and external, no all database so any idea or example explicit please??

i use mysql, the replication i dont like because is for all database and i need use only one table external.

tnks!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you want to know how to use a different database for one or more models in your app.

You can do this quite simply in Rails. First, you'll have to create another entry in your `config/database.yml` file:

```
production:
  ....

development:
  ...

test:
  ...

# Our external database
external: 
  adapter: mysql
  host: some_host
  username: some_username
  password: some_password
  database: some_db
```

Then, in your model, simply tell Rails that for this particular model, use a different connection:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :external
end
```

This will send any queries for MyModel to the external database, while all other models will use the production/development database as usual.

Please note that when you're using two different databases together, MySQL itself will not let you perform certain functions, such as joins. Otherwise, you should be fine with this approach.

Comment: tnks vonconrad, im use your solution, i will tell you how work it. tnks again.

Comment: hi vonconrad, try it your solution, but now, how save record with new connection.

Comment: Saving shouldn't be any different to any other queries. What error message are you getting?

Comment: in my user_controller call this commercial=Commercial::User.new(params[:user]) and next line commercial.save so and in my model commercial.rb i have your solution, but simply does not show error, but does nothing

Answer (score 1):

well my solution is the next with help vonconrad post.

database.yml

like of vonoconrad post

MyModelconn.rb

```
class MyModelconnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  # No corresponding table in the DB.
  self.abstract_class = true

  # Open a connection to the appropriate database depending
  # on what RAILS_ENV is set to.
  establish_connection(:connyml)
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

In users_controller.rb where i need insert into in external table with data values where i save in my Active Record of usres internal so an external  swicht conection next line:

```
MyModelconn.connection.execute('INSERT INTO 'users' (fileld1,filed2)VALUES('#{lcfield1}','#{lcfield2}')')
```

and BINGO! workiT! perfect!

So dont need you again swicht back AR internal.